# How to fix multiple association relashionships using a tuple?

Tags: c++, types, associations

I made a simple system to deal with associations (I made one-to-one associations and one-to-multiple associations but I will focus on the one-to-one case here). It is working as I wish if an object has only one type of association but I need to deal with several types of associations (ie. an object a0 of type A is associated to an object b0 of type B and to another object c0 of type C).
I tried to do it by encapsulating the association class in a tuple (if there is a better/simpler method to do this, please tell me) but I have a problem with types now. Here is my current code (some templates are not used right now, like ind1, but I might need it later):

```
template <typename A1, typename A2, size_t ind1, size_t ind2>
class Association
{
public:
    virtual ~Association()
    {
        if (!this->empty())
        {
            this->clear_associations();
        }
    }

    void associate(A2* ref)
    {
        if (!this->empty() && _ref == ref)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_ref)
        {
            std::get<ind2>(*_ref).reset_association();
        }

        _ref = ref;
        std::get<ind2>(*ref).associate(static_cast<A1*>(this));
    };

    void associate(A2& ref)
    {
        this->associate(&ref);
    };

    bool empty() const
    {
        if (!_ref)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void remove_association(A2* ref)
    {
        if (_ref == ref)
        {
            this->reset_association();
            std::get<ind2>(ref)->remove_association(static_cast<A1*>(this));
        }
    }

    void remove_association(A2& ref)
    {
        this->remove_association(&ref);
    }

    void reset_association()
    {
        _ref = 0;
    }

    void clear_associations()
    {
        if (_ref)
        {
            std::get<ind2>(_ref)->remove_association(static_cast<A1*>(this));
        }
        this->reset_association();
    }

    A2* get_association() const
    {
        return _ref;
    }

private:
    A2* _ref=0;
};

template <typename... T>
class Relations : public std::tuple<T...>
{
public:
    Relations();
    virtual ~Relations();
};

class J;
class K;

class I : public Relations<Association<I, J, 0, 0>, Association<I, K, 1, 0>>
{
public:
    std::string type="I";
};

class J : public Relations<Association<J, I, 0, 0>>
{
public:
    std::string type="J";
};

class K : public Relations<Association<K, I, 0, 1>>
{
public:
    std::string type="K";
};

int main()
{
    I i;
    J j;
    K k;
    std::get<0>(i).associate(j);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that when I try to do std::get(*ref).associate(static_cast(this)); A1 is of type I while this is of type Association which can't be casted directly due to the tuple. What is the good way to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create your own get for `Relation`:

```
namespace std
{
    template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
    auto get(Relations<Ts...>& r)
    -> typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type&
    {
        return static_cast<typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type&>(r);
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/lID4Jk).

Comment: Wow, I had no idea we could write such thinks. What does mean the -> after the get function? Do you have any link for some documentation about it please? Anyway your solution works like a charm so thank you very much! :)

Comment: It is called *trailing return type*.

Comment: Thanks I will check that.